# Is this effective enough to stop email spam-bots?

Tags: php, email, obfuscation

So for my responsive site, when in the mobile-scale, I have an "Email Us" button that the user can tap to open up the email client.

Originally this was a simple mailto:, but I've since changed it, but as I wanted to keep the changes to an absolute minimum, I decided upon the following method:

Replace the `"mailto:example@email.com` with a link to `redirect.php` in my site directory.
All that is in `redirect.php` is this:

```
<?php

    header('Location: mailto:example@email.com');
    exit();

?>
```

And it behaves totally fine!
That was the only spot where the email address was present in the HTML or JS, so I felt like it would be overkill to do a complete encryption of the email.

So my question is this: Is this enough to effectively keep spam-bots out?
If no, what extra steps are necessary?

Obviously you can't 100% stop them from happening, but I figured as the actual address is only on the server-side, that would significantly reduce the risk.
Right?

Comment: You're still broadcasting the email address. Keep it behind closed doors at all times.

Comment: It's a workaround. Actually somewhat clever. But unlikely to deter well-written spiders.

Comment: @JohnConde Yeah, you're right, I can see it via the web inspector... well, guess I'll have to rethink it a bit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @mario heh thanks, I certainly thought so.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it is not wrong and can help you a lot, however if you really want to kill spam the best way is to use a Captcha, even if basic.

If I were you I would try this method for some time and if you keep receiving spam, I would introduce a simple Captcha in a lightbox with a button asking if the user is human. If so the user would be redirected to your redirect.php

I think this way is simple for the user to press a button, for you to implement and would kill 95% of bots.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this question will always be no, as even if you come up with a new way of obfuscating your email address that nobody has ever used before, the bots will be modified to get around it eventually

I find that building the address with Javascript is still an effective solution, as crawlers generally don't parse javascript for various reasons

Comment: I've seen bots parse the source with a series of regular expessions to nail down the E-mail address when using JS, it's a very rare occasion that they do it, but it can be done. Bots will only be modified to keep up to a standard which is publicly/majority used